# Get View Name where ViewResult.ViewName is empty string for Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I have written an extension method on ActionResult for use in unit testing which will assert whether the ViewName returned is what was expected.  This is the code I have so far:

```
public static void AssertViewWasReturned(this ActionResult result, string viewName)
{
    string actualViewName;

    if (result is ViewResult)
        actualViewName = (result as ViewResult).ViewName;
    else if (result is PartialViewResult)
        actualViewName = (result as PartialViewResult).ViewName;
    else
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Results of type " + result.GetType() + " don't have a ViewName");

    Assert.AreEqual(viewName, actualViewName, string.Format("Expected a View named{0}, got a View named {1}", viewName, actualViewName));
}
```

This works fine except where the controller returns a View without specifying a name - in this case `result.ViewName` is an empty string.

So, my question is - is there any well of telling from a ViewResult object what the name of the View was where ViewName is an empty string?

Comment: Is there any real need to test the view name? I think it's sufficient to know that view name will be the same as action name

Comment: The View name will often be different to the action name, as one of the overloads for View() allows you to pass the ViewName.

Comment: If the view name is different you need to specify it explicitly, so the check for empty string will fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your controller-method is not called through the MVC pipeline, additional information are not added to the `Controller.ViewData` dictionary (which I assumed would somehow provide an "action"-key, but couldn't confirm). But since you using your controller "outside" the context of the routing-framework etc. there is no way it knows about the called method.

So the answer is simply "no". If the name of the view was not specified, you cannot determine it from the ViewResult returned by the action. At least not in the way your controller is being tested (which is totally fine by the way).

Comment: @StanK: I ran in the same problem. I just made checking for the right view-name another test. Just fyi, `PartialViewResult` and `ViewResult` both share the base class `ViewResultBase` which provides a `ViewName` property, also you can use the `Assert.IsInstanceOfType` method to check the type and get a nice error message.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth - I've revised my test my extension method like this (incorporating J. Tihon's feedback):

```
public static void AssertViewWasReturned(this ActionResult result, string viewName, string defaultViewName)
{    
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<ViewResultBase>(result, "Result is not an instance of ViewResultBase");
    var viewResult = (ViewResultBase)result;

    var actualViewName = viewResult.ViewName;

    if (actualViewName == "")
        actualViewName = defaultViewName;

    Assert.AreEqual(viewName, actualViewName, string.Format("Expected a View named{0}, got a View named {1}", viewName, actualViewName));
}
```

This means that my unit tests can contain code like this:

```
var result = controller.MyAction();
result.AssertViewWasReturned("ExpectedViewName","MyAction")
```

It's not as good as I'd hoped, as I need to specify the 'defaultViewName' (i.e. the action name) but is a reasonable comprimise.

Answer (score 3):

You could update your controllers to always pass the view you want.

Instead of:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Do this instead:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Either that or change your unit test code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I am understanding your question, but if the `View()` method is called with no parameters, MVC will look for a View with the name of the calling action method, in a directory named as the Controller (without the "Controller" suffix added onto the name).

For instance, this Action:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        // some code here
        return View();
    }
}
```

Because this is an empty `View()` call, MVC will look for the View with the path and filename of `~\Views\User\SomeAction.cshtml`.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I understand  that.  I'm thinking from a unit testing point of view.  If we take your example above, if I was testing it using my extension method above, I'd go `var controller = new UserController(); var result = controller.SomeAction(); result.AssertViewWasReturned("SomeAction");`  With my current code the final assertion would fail.

Comment: @StanK can't you just pass a constructed `string` to the `result.AssertviewWasReturned()` method?  Something like `string ViewAndPath = controller.GetType().ToString().Substring(0, ....) + ...`.  Basically get the controller name minus "controller", and the method name, which would be the Action.  This would point you to the exact View that is used.  Make sense?

Comment: I could - but that would defeat the purpose of the test.  My test is designed to assert that the controller method returned what I expected it to.  The only way to do this is to examine the ViewResult.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your view name while returning.

Ex:

```
Public ActionResult Index(){

// your code

Return View("YourViewName", DataToSendForView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the controller. The `OnResultExecuted` Method is the point in the controller lifecycle where there is a view available.

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext ctx)
{
    base.OnResultExecuted(ctx);
    String ViewPath = ((System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView)((System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase)ctx.Result).View).ViewPath.ToString();
}
```