# Writing a unit test for a Custom ViewEngine in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a ViewEngine (for Desktop, Tablet, IPhone):

```cs
public ViewEngine()
{
    Set 3 Locations
};

public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                                            string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
{
    Assign view locations...
}
```

Then I created a Unit Test class:

```cs
[Test]
public void Test_IPad_UserAgent()
{
    var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    var controller = new PaymentController();

    controllerContext.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent).Returns("Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10");

    controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;
    var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
    var viewData = result.ViewData;

}
```

My Question is, How do I write a assert to check whether my view engine returns correct view for different UserAgent strings?

I m happy to provide full code for ViewEngine If anyone happy to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the ViewEngineCollection property for the adequate ViewEngine you're looking for. Try something like:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOf<MyCustomViewEngine>(result.ViewEngineCollection.First());
```

If you need to test anything beyond the type of the ViewEngine, like the actual View that was returned, I'd suggest you to provide such information through your custom ViewEngine, in your FindView method. You could, for example, provide some info in the ViewData and check for that info in your tests. For example:

```
view.ViewData.Add("path", "MyCustomPath/" + partialViewName;
```

Refer to this question for more info why that is necessary: [Get View Name where ViewResult.ViewName is empty string for Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301797/get-view-name-where-viewresult-viewname-is-empty-string-for-unit-testing)